# include header php inside every file

Tags: php, header, include

i am trying to include a php header inside each of the pages i make. Now as far as i know, it can be done by using `<?php include('header.php'); ?>`inside each file.

Now my problem is that i have 5 pages, and in the header php i have a nav which links to each of  this pages. When i load the header i would like to change the link of the file which the header is loaded on.

Ex: if i open the Home page, i want the header to have the link inside the header nav bolded.
That would probably require me to send a variable to the header file when i include it or smt? if so, than how to do that ? :D

Thank you in advance, Daniel!

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)?

Comment: I believe you're looking for this solution http://www.apaddedcell.com/how-automatically-include-your-header-navigation-and-footer-every-page Also look up php frameworks

Comment: edit header.php to use $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] to get current page and alter the Nav accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either do this by setting a variable before including the header or by looking at the URL.

A simplified example:

```
$page = "home";
include "header.php"
```

In `header.php`

```
if ($page == "home") { ... }
```

The following code will give you the file name from the URL

```
$basename = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

So if you have `http://mysite.com/index.php` it'll give you `index.php`

You can use this in your `header.php` similarly to how I described above to decide which link to bold.

Comment: Ah beat me to it. I would always suggest the latter. Its easier to maintain, and also not as confusing.

Comment: wow this is great, i just used this idea and it works great :D Thank you very much for this and also @ Aleks G and Kuba Wyrostek i will try that aswell to see how it works later on when i will try to develop a little framework :D

Answer (score 2):

You can always use `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` to obtain the name of the most outer php file that was requested. Than you can change style of link in navigation accordingly, ie:

```
 <a href="some.php" style="font-weight: <?= $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] == '/some.php' ? 'bold' : 'normal' ?>">Link to Some</a>
 <a href="other.php" style="font-weight: <?= $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] == '/other.php' ? 'bold' : 'normal' ?>">Link to Other</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to check the name of the executing script from your header file, something like this (inside header.php):

```
$page = basename($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
if($page == 'index.php') {
    //header included from inside index.php
}
elseif($page == 'contact.php') {
    //header included from contact.php
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

In below code, you can call this class to other pages and pass the page name as parameters and can call a jQuery function with that very easily

```
<?php
class header {
function __construct($title = "Home", $page = 'home') {
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
            <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.<?php echo $page ?>').addClass('active');
            });    
        </script> 
        </head>
<body>
     <ul class="nav">
        <li class="home"><a href="index.php"><br />HOME<br /></a></li>
         <li class="about"><br />ABOUT US<br /></li>
     </ul>
<?php }} ?>
```

Comment: this is also great but i'm trying to do more html / css stuff and use jQuery only when i cant do it witohut it. voted up, thank you very much :)